# Wpf Control with WindowsFormsHost overrides MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, windowsformshost

I have MainWindow with ScrollViewer inside a Grid. The ScrollViewer contains UserControl that is used to display a list of items and scroll inside the bounds of the MainWindow Grid.

The problem is when I scroll the content the WindowsFormsHost is rendered in top of the MainWindow outside the MainWindow/Grid bounds.

How can I render the WindowsFormsHost inside the MainWindow Grid?

Thank you.

Comment: this is called "Airspace issue", as far as I know it is still not fixed in WPF, but you may try google for possible workarounds like [this one](https://insertbreakpoint.wordpress.com/2016/12/20/vertical-airspace/)

Answer (score 1):

Every control from WindowsForm ms is rendered always on top. You cannot do anything about that. I had the same problem with WebBrowser as it is WindowsForms control it overrided my notifications. As I result I was forced to search for alternatives such as Chromium for .NET.